# How does Angular use _page-theme.scss resources?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

In the Angular Material Documentation the home page has the following scss file:

```
https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/app/pages/homepage/_homepage-theme.scss
```

I don't see this imported into the file that `scss` file that is declared by the component.  How does Angular become aware of this file / styling?

These are all the homepage files:

https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/tree/master/src/app/pages/homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scss file is imported in the main scss. go to =>[https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/master/src/_app-theme.scss][1]

and this line : `@import './app/pages/homepage/homepage-theme';`

But you can do something like that directly in your scss file from the component  :

```
@import './homepage-theme';
```